# javascript stopwatch limit maximum time

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript stopwatch displaying the time in MM:SS (minutes:seconds). If the time reaches 59:59 MM:SS then it should be automatically stopping (until the user hits Clear and Start again) instead of increasing to 60:00, 60:01 etc. **How do I set a maximum time to prevent this?** The code below allows the user to Stop, Start, Clear, and Save the Stopwatch which is perfect minus limiting the maximum time permitted on the javascript. Any help or links to documentation would be appreciated.

**javascript:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var clsStopwatch = function () {

var startAt = 0;
var lapTime = 0;

var now = function () {
return (new Date()).getTime();
};

this.start = function () {
startAt = startAt ? startAt : now();
};

this.stop = function () {
lapTime = startAt ? lapTime + now() - startAt : lapTime;
startAt = 0;
};

this.clear = function () {
lapTime = 0;
startAt = 0;
};

this.time = function () {
return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0);
};
};

var x = new clsStopwatch();
var $time;
var clocktimer;

function pad(num, size) {
var s = "0000" + num;
return s.substr(s.length - size);
}

function formatTime(time) {
var h = m = s = 0;
var newTime = '';

m = Math.floor(time / (60 * 1000));
time = time % (60 * 1000);
s = Math.floor(time / 1000);

newTime = pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2);
return newTime;
}

function show() {
$time = document.getElementById('time');
update();
}

function update() {
$time.innerHTML = formatTime(x.time());
}

function start() {
clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
x.start();
}

function stop() {
x.stop();
document.getElementById('counter').value = formatTime(x.time());
clearInterval(clocktimer);
}

function save() {
x.stop();
document.getElementById('counter').value = formatTime(x.time());
clearInterval(clocktimer);           
}

function clearWatch() {
x.stop();
x.clear();
clearInterval(clocktimer);
update();
}

</script>
```

**html/php:**

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST"/>
<h1>Time: <span id="time"></span> <br/></h1> 
<!--<input type="text" name-"time">-->
<input type="hidden" value="" id="counter" name="counter">
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start();">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();">
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearWatch();">
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="save();">
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: "I have a javascript stopwatch displaying the time in MM:SS (minutes:seconds). If the time reaches 59:59 MM:SS then it should be automatically stopping (until the user hits Clear and Start again) instead of increasing to 60:00, 60:01 etc." How is that not a question my objective is to specify a maximum time. That should be clear in the topic as well.

Comment: It's not a question because it's not a question, sorry. "That should be clear in the topic as well" --- we have no idea why you currently is in stuck. It's just `if (time passed > 60 minutes) { ... }` logic.

Comment: "How do I set a maximum time to prevent this?" --- you just check on every tick how much time passed. So additionally to outputting how much passed you need to check it.

Comment: Sorry I only know php. I'm trying to figure this out myself. So I should put something in this function?    : this.time = function () {
return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0);
};
}; right?

Comment: you would put it in the update function since that's what you are calling every second.

Comment: It's not that js-specific. How would you do that if it was php?

Comment: It is javascript specific because I'm trying to do it with JAVASCRIPT. I'll verify the input with php as well which is easy for me.

Comment: It's not JS programming question, it's a question about using `if`, which is pretty much the same as it is in php

Comment: Stop lecturing me. Every language has it's own syntax so yes it is javascript specific. Obviously I don't know javascript syntax in its most entry level form, which is why I'm asking. Please don't post on this topic anymore. I don't want your two cents.

Comment: The syntax of `if` is trivial (it's the same as in php): `if (condition) stmt;`. But I see that you're here not to learn but to find someone to do your job for you for free.

Comment: "Any help or links to documentation" --- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the time function so that if time is greater than the value you have as max then it returns max.

```
this.time = function () {
    var duration = lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0);
    if (duration > max) {
        duration = max;
    }
    return duration ;
};
```

Replace max with numerical value representing the maximum duration.

For 59:59, The max value would be (1000 * 60 * 59) + (59 * 1000). This is because the time representation returned is a millisecond value, so 59 minutes plus 59 seconds

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot. I'm not going to comment here anymore since it's so toxic.

Comment: I think they were just trying to point out that it is just an if statement in the right place which is the same across most languages with minor syntactic differences.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother. I used the this.time = function () precisely as seen above and set duration > 5  and duration = 5 just to test it (I assume this means 5 seconds), however the counter failed to start when I clicked 'Start'.

Comment: That means 5 milliseconds.. see my update. 5 seconds would be 5000